# PHP Mail code won't send the right characters

Tags: php

sorry to disturb you, but I've made this code, It was longer but I made it to this because this is the part that won't send the right stuff

```
    <?php
    mail('mitchg345@yahoo.com', "Welcome!", "Welcome", "FROM: Mitch");
    echo "Good";
    ?>
```

The From just keeps saying it's from "Nobody" but the "Welcome!" part works, but after that doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: I believe From: needs to have a email, not just a name, or name and email: 
From: Mitch <mitch@example.com>

Comment: You should check out this question / answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014081/problem-with-php-mail-from-header][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014081/problem-with-php-mail-from-header

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [PHP mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
if(mail('mitchg345@yahoo.com', 'Subject', 'Message', 'From: Mitch <mitchg345@yahoo.com>'))
{
    echo 'Sent';
}
```