# Email header not working PHP

Tags: php, email, header, bluehost

I'm using BlueHost and I can't seem to get my email form to work. This is the PHP:

```
$to = "test@email.com";
$subject = "test";
$message = "test message";
$from =  $_POST['cf_email'];
$headers = "From: $from";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo $headers;
```

This doesn't seem to send the email. However, if I add ANY string in front of the email, then it works. e.g.:

```
$from =  "zz".$_POST['cf_email'];
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What's inside `$_POST['cf_email']`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use any personal email ($_POST['cf_email']) in the 'From' header. 
Also you have to add 'reply-to'.

Please check below thread for more info.

[problem with php mail 'From' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014081/problem-with-php-mail-from-header)