# contact form - using gmail smtp server - how to show customer email when using contact form in php

Tags: php, mysql, contact-form

Ive built a contact form and it works perfectly apart from one issue. It does not show the customers email address when testing the form. It only shows email sent to 'me' and the message.

im using the following php code:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if (empty($name) === true || empty($email) === true || empty($message) === true) {
$errors[] = 'Name, email and message are required!';
} else {
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
$errors[] = 'That\'s not a valid email address';
}
if (ctype_alpha($name) === false) {
$errors[] = 'Name must only contain letters!';
}
} 

if (empty($errors) === true) {
mail('*****', 'Question', $message, 'From: ' . $email);
header('Location: contactus.php?sent');
exit(); 
}

}
?>
```

The whole point of the contact us form would be so that the business has the name and email of the person who has contacted them.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that your host/ISP/OS etc will not allow you to send mail from email address that does not belong to you - [problem with php mail 'From' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014081/problem-with-php-mail-from-header) and therefore you will not see the email address!

Better idea to to append $email to $message or something similar.

```
$message="FROM: $email /n " . $message;
mail('*****', 'Question', $message, 'From: ' . $email);
```

Comment: Thank you very much neyl, that has fixed the issue I was having.