# When receiving email's I only get my email address as "sent from." although it was sent from another email address. What should I add or change?

Tags: php, email

So I'm using this code for php mail and I keep getting MY email address rather than the actualy senders email, when I test it on my website's contact form. Any help? By the way, I use my email in the recipients address.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$call = $_POST['call'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$priority = $_POST['priority'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back: $call \n Type: $type \n  Message:      $message";
$recipient = "myemail@address.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
?>
```

Comment: Check out the top answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014081/problem-with-php-mail-from-header)

Comment: Try to incorporate `\r\n` in `$recipient = "myemail@address.com";` and in `$subject = "Contact Form";` and also try removing the space between `$email` and `\r\n";`. I've seen that issue before. *Servers are strange animals sometimes.*

Comment: Still no luck. I did exactly as you said and still receive emails from  my own email address.

Comment: I tried something else and added \n to the $formcontent :D

Comment: @EstebanRodriguez I thought of that earlier actually, but didn't think that was the issue. Oh well, if it works now, great!

Comment: @EstebanRodriguez It "does" work for you now, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [php:mail manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) in the example#3 you can see,

```
<?php
mail('nobody@example.com', 'the subject', 'the message', null,'-fwebmaster@example.com');
?>
```

You can see

> The additional_parameters parameter can be used to pass an additional parameter to the program configured to use when sending mail using the sendmail_path.

Comment: I'm a PHP noob, so can you break it down to me? What exactly do I put in my form in order to get emails displaying the actual senders email rather than my email?