# How to send PHP mail with HTML formatting

Tags: email, php

Everything was working ok until i added HTML. This code is sending the Email with an address as my hosting account username not the email i'm specifying.

```
$from = "info@site.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from. "\r\n";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

After sending, the email is from some weird User@gdfgdfhgfdf bla bla intead of 'info@site.com';

and i assume it's my headers.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem with php mail 'From' header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014081/problem-with-php-mail-from-header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting your headers, by using the = sign twice in a row, the second line should be

```
$headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including your `$from` inside the `$headers` like this.

```
$from = "info@site.com";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: InfoSite <'.$from.'>'."\r\n"; //<--- Like this.
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: Why do you have `From:` twice? And if you're going to put a name before the address, you have to put the address inside `<...>`.

Comment: is infosite the full site like www.site.com? on line four

Comment: Nope you can put any text there.