# Issue with headers in sending emails in PHP

Tags: php, email

Hello I'm using PHP built in php mail() and using this function s=to send emails :

```
function sendEmail($to,$subject,$message){
   $header = 'From: noreply@xxxxx.com' . "\r\n" .
   'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
   'Content-type: text/html' . "\r\n" ;
   $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
   if( $retval == true ){
      return true;
   }
   else{
       return false;
   }
}
```

This function is sending emails but I do receive them not from the "From email" header I set : "noreply@xxxxx.com" but from my host server like this : xxx@host205.hostmonster.com

Why this is not working as I want?

Thanks

Comment: Try `ini_set('sendmail_from', 'example@YourDomain.com');`

Comment: @Termato just wondering, where in there you you see PHPMailer? I would assume from the `mail()` call, it is using the built in php `mail()` function.

Comment: yes sorry built in php mail()

Comment: Also, this stuff is usually covered in your hosting provider's help section. Such as this: https://my.hostmonster.com/hosting/help/206 For stuff related to a specific host, such as configuration, you are usually best off checking there first.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn do you know if Hostmonter and BlueHost are owned by the same company, because both their sites look very similar: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/206 - Edit - Looks like they are the same company, interesting: http://www.10-cheapwebhosting.com/BlueHost-vs-HostMonster.php

Comment: I just went to the site based on the email address you specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a properly formatted "From" statement as follows:

```
 $header = 'From: <noreply@xxxxx.com>' . "\r\n" .
```

or

```
 $header = 'From: "no reply" <noreply@xxxxx.com>' . "\r\n" .
```

and another possible approach could be this: [problem with php mail 'From' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014081/problem-with-php-mail-from-header)