# Laravel mail from not set

Tags: laravel

For my website I try to send emails from an alias (created alias from google for business). My mail function:

```
Mail::send('emails.tracktrace', ['text'=>$mailtext,'tracking' => $code,'email' => $email, 'name' => $name], 
function ($m) use ($code, $email, $name) {
        $m->from('info@mydomain.eu', 'Mydomain');
        $m->to($email, $name)->subject('Track your package!');
});
```

Also in my config/mail.php I have:

```
'from' => ['address' => 'noreply@mydomain.eu', 'name' => 'mydomain'],
```

But both are ignored and the MAIL_USERNAME value set in my .env file (with the mail configuration) is used.

Comment: what is your mail_host, mail_port? can you make sure mail_username and mail_password already correct?

Comment: @sstarlight everything works the mail is send. But the sender is never changed

Comment: as far i read your code it should working properly. I never tried google for business to send via laravel. But as far as i know it should be working. try change `$m` to `$message` and remove `from` mail or the function (so only use 1 `from`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem.. Turned out I tried to use a Gmail account which doesn't let you change the 'from' headers.
(see [problem with php mail 'From' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014081/problem-with-php-mail-from-header))