# Header not display correctly on Email PHP mail

Tags: php, function, email, email-headers

I have the following code to send my emails:

```
$EmailFrom= "staff@homes.com";
$EmailTo = "alejo@yahoo.com, hunterno1@gmail.com";
$Subject = "Contact The Loft";

$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $EmailFrom);
```

When I submit my form it sends the mail correctly but on my email the header is not displayed correctly. Look the following image:

[image: header-mail]

I do not want THEHNOGK@SERVER179.WEB-HOSTING.COM be displayed as the header, so that is why i search thru google and i found out that i need to customize my header. So i did the follow, but now the email is not sent. it seems there is something wrong with the headers:

```
<?php
$EmailFrom= "From: HudsonLofts <staff@hobokenhomes.com>\r\n";
$EmailFrom.= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()."\r\n";
$EmailFrom.= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$EmailFrom.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n";
$EmailTo = "alejo.ferguson@yahoo.com, hunternova01@gmail.com";
$Subject = "Contact The Hudson Loft";
```

And this is where i call the mail function:

```
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $EmailFrom);
```

When i submit the form and check my email account not email is received.

I will appreciate your help. Thanks in advance

I have realized that when i use FROM: the mail is not sent. Moreover the mail function does not work it returns false. BUT it i remove FROM and just use: HudsonLofts then it works but the headers it is not displayed properly on my email :(

Comment: Consult the manual on mail http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php or use phpmailer/swiftmailer. It'll make this a lot easier.

Comment: thanks i will check it

Comment: Btw, I removed the "phpmailer" tag from the question since your syntax isn't "phpmailer", it's "`mail()`", two different animals here.

Comment: thanks i did not find that one so that i use phpmailer instead people will notice it when see the code, but thanks

Comment: Here `$EmailFrom = 'From: HudsonLofts <staff@hobokenhomes.com>' . "\r\n";` that ought to fix this. and possibly `'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";` all taken from "the manual".

Comment: Let me know if that above fixes it ^ and to post an answer for it, given there is one that was posted below but IMHO, don't believe is the solution here and I sure hope he doesn't edit it in regards to what I posted in comments.

Comment: hey this is what i tried: $EmailFrom= 'From: HudsonLofts<staff@hobokenhomes.com>' . "\n";
$EmailFrom.= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$EmailFrom.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; BUT the mail function return false. WIll it be because the rest of the headers are qith quotation marks and not apostrophes? thanks bud!

Comment: I have realized that when i use FROM: the mail is not sent. Moreover the mail function does not work it returns false. BUT it i remove FROM and just use: HudsonLofts<mail@fomain.com> then it works but the headers it is not displayed properly on my email :(

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014081/problem-with-php-mail-from-header

Comment: @CD001 thanks bud! i already tried adding that 5th parameters in that function without sucess

Comment: One of the lower rated answers on that question points out that your email address format is, strictly speaking, invalid so the `From` header *may* fail - try just `From: staff@hobokenhomes.com` - you could also try adding a `Reply-To: staff@hobokenhomes.com` header. There's also the possibility that it's being stripped by the recipient's mail server.

Comment: This is what i tried but not success. thanks though.                    $Headers= "From: staff@hobokenhomes.com";
$Headers.= "Reply-To: staff@hobokenhomes.com". "\n";
$Headers.= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()."\n";

Answer (score 0):

See http://php.net/manual/function.mail.php
Try to use `\n` instead of `\r\n` in `$EmailFrom`.

BTW: I would rename `$EmailFrom` to `$additionalHeaders` ;-)

**EDIT after comment**:
If this doesn't work, try just with this one line for the headers:
`$EmailFrom = "MIME-Version: 1.0";`

Second guess: Omit the `\r\n` at the last header line.

Comment: #1: that shouldn't make a difference. #2: *"BTW: I would rename $EmailFrom to $additionalHeaders"* and do what with that exactly?

Comment: it did not work :( when i try to call mail(to, subject,,,,etc) just return a 0 :( thanks though

Comment: That actually depends quite a **lot** - the RFC specs on line terminators for email headers are `\r\n` - *however* if you're using Postfix as the mailserver that expects the line terminators to be of the form native to the operating system ... practically though, it's unlikely to break either way.

Comment: #1: Well, just following the manual's advice... #2: Just rename it. I (personally) wouldn't call a variable `$EmailFrom` if it holds things like `MIME-Version: 1.0`...

Comment: i did what thomas suggested me but not fixed the issue :( thanks man

Answer (score 0):

```
$EmailFrom= "staff@homes.com";
$EmailTo = "alejo@yahoo.com, hunterno1@gmail.com";
$Subject = "Contact The Loft";

$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $EmailFrom);
```

`$EmailFrom` should be:

```
$EmailFrom= "From: staff@homes.com";
```

or possibly - but I haven't checked this out -

```
$EmailFrom= "From: Staff <staff@homes.com>";
```

since [the fourth parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) allows you to send **any** additional header, not just the From:, and hence you need to specify the full header.

If it still does not work, **be aware that some providers rewrite the From: header** to prevent abuse (such as setting "From: barack.obama@whitehouse.gov"). If this is the case, you won't be able to override that. But you might be able to clear the sender with your provider if you talk to them.

When using the **wrong** form of the parameter, everything "worked" because *you weren't really setting any From field*. When you started doing so, the server might have just dropped the email in the bit bucket without telling you anything; the mail() function would have succeeded, since the mail *was* delivered to the local queue. mail() could not know, much less tell you, that the local queue would then see the mail expunged.