# PHP Mail not sending from "FROM Address"

Tags: php, html, html-email

I do not know why it is not sending from "From" Address but from some
"?@venuse.srv.wz.cz".
I was looking for any solution but i did not find any. Still it sends email from ?@venuse.srv.wz.cz.
 My code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']))
{

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$from = $_POST['email'];
$to = 'filda@seznam.cz';
$subject = 'Kontaktní formulář';
$body = '<html>
<body>
<p>Jméno: '.$name.'</p>
<p>Email: '.$email.'</p>
<p>Zpráva:<br/><br/>'.$_POST['comments'].'</p>
</body></html>';

$headers = "From: ".$email."\r\n"; 
$headers = "Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";

$headers ="Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

$send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

} 
?>
```

Please, does anyone know where could be any mistake?

Comment: hi read this:[check this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014081/problem-with-php-mail-from-header)

Comment: Where is `$_POST` coming from? Try hardcoding `$email` to something. Ex. `$email = 'test@test.com';`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email with PHP from an SMTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server)

Comment: `$email = $_POST['email'];
$from = $_POST['email'];`  should these be the same?

Comment: Yes i think. But still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding headers assigning them to the same variable without concatenation. [Look at example #5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n';
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n';

// Additional headers
$headers .= "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
```

**[EDIT]**
Then as Pawel Szalucki suggested [look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014081/problem-with-php-mail-from-header).

```
$send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f $email");
```

Comment: Still i got email from ?@venuse.srv.wz.cz
and additionaly it makes in message this:
JmĂ©no: Filip

Comment: I've edited the answer with Pawel Szalucki suggestion

Comment: Yes i read that and i tried add this and i still got email from ?@venuse.srv.wz.cz.